# How should I connect mains wires to those in my exterior light?

Tags: wiring

I have an old 500W halogen PIR floodlight secured to an outside wall. It currently has mains wiring coming out the wall and terminating inside the floodlight.
The floodlight has been broken for a while now and I've recently removed it and bought a 50W LED replacement which comes with its own length of wiring. My question is how should I connect the existing mains wire coming out of the wall to the cable coming out of the new floodlight? My initial thought was strip connectors and a junction box, but perhaps solder and heat shrink would be better for outdoors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All connections should be made inside an enclosure with access to it. It could be even the fixture itself. You may use a connection box approved by your local electrical authority.

For connecting two or more wires use existing practice by electricians in your area. In North America we typically use wire nuts. Soldering is not the best practice if you are not experienced in that. Bad soldering may cause oxidation and loss of contact over time, especially outdoors. Other connecting methods require less qualification and effort.

Comment: @user263983 It's also a matter of conductivity. Everybody just assumes solder conducts the same as copper. That ain't nearly so.